# Edge-coloring with constraints (electronics)

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

My work is in electronics modeling, the sought procedure could be helpful in efficiently formulating circuit equations by current and voltage sources only.

For a given circuit topology, assign color/type I (current source) or V (voltage source) to components, such that

- no node/vertex is only connected to type I edges
- no possible mesh/loop/cycle with type V only
- ground is considered type V
- some components could have a fixed or preferred type.

My first approach would be constructive and trying to swap types when conflicts arise.

Are there any heuristics known? I only could find problems like minimum number of types/colors, but not the constraints as described above.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sklq.png)

Minimum spanning tree (Prim's algorithm) with netlist

(node 1 node 2 weight, node numbers see example)

```
0 1 1
1 2 1
2 3 2
3 0 3
```

chooses the spanning (V-type) tree as

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
```

The trick is to apply the correct weights, and these depend on the nature of component (V, I, R, L, C). Then MST gives the correct V branches.

For example, if we have a preference for C-> V (weight = 1) and L->I (weight = 3) and an assumed R||C, the branch preference becomes V, so gets the lowest cost.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What are types I to V ? Besides, this the raw text of your homework (or ongoing exam which would ce the worst). Please, add some sentences coming **from you**, how you have attempted to answer, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Pick a [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree) in the graph. Color all edges in the spanning tree type V (a tree contains no cycles) and color all remaining edges type I. A spanning tree connects all vertices, so no vertex is purely type I.

Comment: Thanks quarague, and I guess the preferences could be incorporated by some weighting.
Need to implement first.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with quarague's hint using a spanning tree and correct weighting, see the example above.

Thanks to all who contributed!